# How to wrap HTML around indexed_search template?

Tags: html, search, typo3, typoscript

I'm trying to wrap HTML around the whole output of the indexed_search extension of Typo3.
In the template there is unfortunately no possibility to do so. I also tried to wrap the tt_content with something like that:

```
tt_content.search.wrap = |</div></div></div><div class="content-2col-right">TEST</div></div>
```

Or

```
tt_content.search.20.stdWrap.wrap = |</div></div></div><div class="content-2col-right">TEST</div></div>
```

Is there a possibility without changing the source code of the extension (which would – without a hook – not be an option).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I solved it with some workarounds:

Deleting the divs, that are wrapped around the tt_content elements (`<div id="c103" class="csc-default">`, etc.) for the specific page with:

```
[globalVar = TSFE:id = 51]
tt_content.stdWrap.innerWrap.cObject >
tt_content.stdWrap.innerWrap.cObject.default >
[global]
```

and adding the wraps as a plain html content element.

Not the best solution, but it works.